# Read and write to data storage offline

Tags: html

I have an offline static hybrid app and I need it to be dynamic just to save contenteditable elements. Any suggestions please?

Notes:
-Database won't work because if i build it as an apk, it can't do SQL commands. (Or maybe I'm wrong?).
-Php won't work because it needs to be on a web server.
-Javascript/JQuery also because it can't write to files. (I guess?)
-I can't download other hybrid app frameworks because of the internet connection. I only have android studio

Answer (score 0):

The general concept is that you have your client-side application communicate with a server-side website (over something like **[AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming))**). The server-side website then makes the database calls, and returns the results back to the client-side application.

This is illustrated in following example.

#### Client-side (application):

```
// Initialise the HTTP request
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'ABSOLUTE-URL.php');

// Track the state changes of the request
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
            console.log(xhr.responseText); // Output from PHP
        } else {
            console.log('Error: ' + xhr.status); // Errors in the process
        }
    }
};

// Send the request to PHP
xhr.send(null);
```

#### Server-side (hosted on a website):

```
<?php

// Make the SQL query
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$results = ...

// Echo the results back to the client
echo $results;

?>
```

With the above, whatever gets echo'd out on the server-side is what is passed back to the client-side application. From here you can format it and display it to the user.

If you need to process data **offline**, your best bet is to make use of **[localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)**. This is ideal for things like remembering usernames (but not passwords) in login forms, so that users don't have to re-enter them every time they go to log in to your application.

Comment: Thank you. But I need to do this locally because it is a stand-alone hybrid app. I can't do PHP's because I can't embed local webservers to run instantly when the app is started

Comment: I assume you're using something like Cordova? In such a case, I would still recommend this approach. You would leave your web server running all the time (likely hosted), and simply have your application make requests that hit the server, like a regular user on a browser would. Is there a particular reason you need a *local* web server or to fire it up specifically when the app is started by an individual user? Surely you would have multiple users using the application at any one time.

Comment: It's just a school work, so I don't want to pay for web server. And free web servers mostly fails, like locking my created site. Thanks btw

Comment: I'll just do it on 000webhost. I guess deploying it on free hosting would be the easiest way.

Comment: I personally wouldn't recommend 000webhost, as [*they store passwords in plaintext*](https://www.troyhunt.com/breaches-traders-plain-text-passwords/). Deployment on a free server is probably the easiest though, and there's always localStorage too :)

Comment: Will local storage help me? Will javascript be able to write on text files with the help of local storage? And can you recommend any free hosting with database and easy to use like 000webhost.